# String output incomplete - Strange behavior

Tags: c++, string, console-application, cout, wstring

Strangely, the following string stops before the end:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::wcout;
using std::wstring;


int main()
{
    wstring test = L"Os elfos compõem uma raça atlética e esguia, da mesma altura dos humanos. Eles apresentam a mesma variedade de compleições dos humanos, mas costumam ser mais bronzeados ou morenos. A cor típica do cabelo de um elfo é marrom escuro, ruivo escuro, verde musgo ou dourado escuro. As orelhas dos elfos são longas e pontiagudas, seus olhos são azuis, violetas ou verdes vibrantes. Esse povo tem poucos pêlos no corpo, mas prefere manter uma aparência selvagem e embaraçada nos cabelos.\nOs elfos atingem a maturidade na mesma velocidade que os humanos, mas demonstram pouquíssimos efeitos do envelhecimento depois da idade adulta. O primeiro sinal da idade avançada de um elfo geralmente é uma mudança na cor dos cabelos — muitas vezes ficando grisalhos, mas quase sempre escurecendo ou assumindo cores mais castanhas. A maioria dos elfos vive bem até os 200 anos de idade e permanecem vigorosos até o fim.";
    wcout << test;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Os elfos comp§em uma raþa atlÚtica e esguia, da mesma altura dos humanos. Eles apresentam a mesma variedade de compleiþ§es dos humanos, mas costumam ser mais bronzeados ou morenos. A cor tÝpica do cabelo de um elfo Ú marrom escuro, ruivo escuro, verde musgo ou dourado escuro. As orelhas dos elfos sÒo longas e pontiagudas, seus olhos sÒo azuis, violetas ou verdes vibrantes. Esse povo tem poucos pÛlos no corpo, mas prefere manter uma aparÛncia selvagem e embaraþada nos cabelos.
Os elfos atingem a maturidade na mesma velocidade que os humanos, mas demonstram pouquÝssimos efeitos do envelhecimento depois da idade adulta. O primeiro sinal da idade avanþada de um elfo geralmente Ú uma mudanþa na cor dos cabelos
```

Correct Ouput:

```
Os elfos comp§em uma raþa atlÚtica e esguia, da mesma altura dos humanos. Eles apresentam a mesma variedade de compleiþ§es dos humanos, mas costumam ser mais bronzeados ou morenos. A cor tÝpica do cabelo de um elfo Ú marrom escuro, ruivo escuro, verde musgo ou dourado escuro. As orelhas dos elfos sÒo longas e pontiagudas, seus olhos sÒo azuis, violetas ou verdes vibrantes. Esse povo tem poucos pÛlos no corpo, mas prefere manter uma aparÛncia selvagem e embaraþada nos cabelos.
Os elfos atingem a maturidade na mesma velocidade que os humanos, mas demonstram pouquÝssimos efeitos do envelhecimento depois da idade adulta. O primeiro sinal da idade avanþada de um elfo geralmente Ú uma mudanþa na cor dos cabelos — muitas vezes ficando grisalhos, mas quase sempre escurecendo ou assumindo cores mais castanhas. A maioria dos elfos vive bem até os 200 anos de idade e permanecem vigorosos até o fim.
```

It stops always on the same part "... cabelos".
What is happening? 
If I divide the string in smaller chunks, it behaves properly. Is it the issue, string size?

Comment: Trash your compiler? Because it prints normally in ideone.com - http://ideone.com/ddBUh6

Comment: Compiler version, standard library version, OS? Also, you might try setting the locale with `std::locale::global( std::locale( "" ) );`. The `—` character here looks suspicious; unlike the other characters it might translate to an invalid sequence in the encoding used by the terminal.

Comment: Have you tried a far shorter string, maybe 10 characters?

Comment: force a flush, wcout [<<....] << std::endl;

Comment: Try it with just `cabelos — muitas`.

Comment: Seems like a encoding issue, since *compõem* get's *comp§em*... And the dash behind "cabelos" isn't a simple minus...

Comment: The dash is unicode `0x2014`

Comment: Maybe compiler should be it???

@Potatoswatter Yes, in another test. It didn't work.

Comment: @orlando2bjr: could you please trim down your example, the wrong output and the correct output to something one can easily grasp? it's not that helpfull to have 492 chars in a row and to have to scan them in different scrollable textareas...

Comment: @PeterWood YESSSS. In fact, the character — was different from - and caused the whole situation. Since I copied and pasted it from another source, It never occurred to me this character would be a problem.

Comment: I have the same output at MinGW 4.6.2 on Win7. Even if I try to output `cabelos — muitas` I got only `cabelos`.

Comment: @akira How can I format it to wrap? I couldn't trim down because I didn't know where/what the error was (size, character, etc) until now.

Comment: @Aschratt The compõem/comp§em issue has already been solved. I just didn't want to clutter the code with extra lines.

Comment: @borisbn Just so you know too, that character was the problem. I changed it to minus symbol, but I wonder which hex code I should use to input that symbol without an error.

Comment: I searched `ascii dash` and found `150` for `ndash` and `151` for `mdash` (narrow and wide dashes, take your pick).

Comment: thanks again, @PeterWood. I tested them and then I got error again. I tested it with \u2014 and \x0151, but them the problem reappears. I think, as SChepurin, this may be a compiler limitation.

Comment: BTW, @PeterWood, you should post your answer so I can vote on it ;-)

Comment: @orlando2bjr: multiple lines?

Comment: @akira I thought that way would break the code for those trying to reproduce the error. Or, at least, give them extra work to "unbreak" the lines. I wish there was some code wrapping with line numbers in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the characters around where it stops printing to see what they were in unicode.

Your hyphen is actually a unicode dash `0x2014`.

This outputs a null to the stream and terminates the string.

When faced with a large amount of code, data, features, or changes it's best to put on blinkers and chop it down into into smaller pieces. Sometimes it's best to chop it in half, then half again, then again, until it's manageable. Other times, just strip down to nothing, then add in a little at a time.